# Are private member variables really thread safe in asp.net code behind class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, thread-safety

**I am seeing a random exception "Collection was modified; enumeration may not execute" - InvalidOperationException.**

The exception points to foreach line in the code snippet below, I know this happens when a collection is modified while enumerating.

**However in my scenario, I don't see a real chance of it happening - UNLESS private member is not thread safe.. I may be wrong, but this where I need help to understand and figure out**.

Here is how my code looks

I have code behind class which has a private collection like

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _someDictionary = SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue;
```

In the page prerender complete event, I am enumerating the dictionary

```
protected override void OnPagePreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e){
     _someDictionary["AnotherKey"] = "Another value";

     foreach(var dataValuePair in _SomeDictionary){
         //Do some operation
     }
}
```

I also have a public property which can modify this collection, but it set in the ascx file like

```
<tc: UserControlA runat="server" id="abc" CustomProperty="true" />
```

and here is its implementation,

```
public bool CustomProperty{
    set{
         if (value)
            _someDictionary["CustomProperty"] = "Custom Value";
    }
}
```

It certainly modified my member variable collection - But as per my understanding this property should be fired and done in the Control Init itself.

So, I still dont see a scenario where the collection is modified during the pre render complete event.

Any idea what could cause the exception to occur??

**other notes:** the page certainly has many update panels though this specific usercontrol does not do anything fancy and does not even have postback scenario. 
From the log I see that the issue is happening in HTTP GET request to the page.

Moreover: Suggest me a way (if any) to reproduce this.

For my friends who were interested to know the SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue, here it is

```
class SomeConstantClass{
  public static Dictionary<string, string> ConstantValue = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                      {"ABCD", "EFGH"},
                      {"HIJK", "LMNO"}
                   };
  }
```

Comment: What is SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue? Is this static?

Comment: It's interesting that you leave out the actual code that is executing inside the one of the first places we'd look.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram are you interested in knowing what is inside the foreach loop?

Comment: The implementation of `SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue` is also of interest.

Comment: @KeYan : yes; it is quite likely the code in the loop causing the exception.

Comment: @AndrewBarber; @AnthonyPergram - I can assure you that code inside the foreach is not modifying the collection. It just builds a string from values in dictionary.

Comment: @KeYan, as stated in my answer the problem is that `SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue` is a static object.

Comment: @KeYan Nevermind. Looks like it's solved.

Comment: I agree with @JoãoAngelo if the loop is clean. Forget the private variable, it's irrelevant. The actual object it references is global.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are returning the same instance from `SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue` then multiple pages will have the private member variable pointing to the same object. This will lead to the object being changed on the init of one page while its being iterated on the `OnPagePreRenderComplete` of another page.

Make sure that you return a new instance of the dictionary in each access to `SomeConstantClass.ConstantValue`. Example:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ConstantValue
{
    get
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"ABCD", "EFGH"},
            {"HIJK", "LMNO"}
        };
    }
}
```

This way each page will have it own dictionary object to work with. This is the quick solution, you could refactor the logic so that you don't need to have to create a new dictionary for each page.

Basically private member variables are only thread safe if they reference an object that is private to that page and no one else knows about that object or the object itself is designed to be thread-safe. Encapsulating access to a non thread-safe static object through a private member will not make it thread safe.

Comment: Encapsulating access to a non thread-safe static object through a private member will not make it thread safe. - The point I did not realize.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you know you're not sharing the dictionary across requests (or you are purposely doing that) you can skip trying to figure out why, and just use a [Concurrent Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which is thread safe.  Just because a Dictionary is private doesn't make it thread safe.

Comment: -1 Using a concurrent dictionary and sharing it in all pages will mean the `CustomProperty="true"` on the user control is pointless since any item a page adds to the dictionary will also visible to other pages.